# How Do We Access Sonoma Password Manager Items from the Command Line?

Tags: macos, command-line, security

I have some automation that uses `/usr/bin/security` to pull data from my Keychain. I want to move this data to the new Password Manager (Settings.app ->  Passwords), but I can't find the items in any of the listed Keychains. Nor can I find new options for `/usr/bin/security` to look in the super-secret keychain. Anyone know how to access this data from the command line?